# Calling managed code in CLR application

Tags: dll, delegates, interop, c++-cli, export

I've got the following function in a C++/CLI class library DLL:

```
public delegate void StandardOutputError(String^ Message);

bool foo(System::String^% arg1, System::String^% arg2, System::String^% arg3, StandardOutputError^ Output);
```

How would I go about exporting it so that it can be called by arbitrary managed (C++/CLI) code ?  My primary concern is the delegate argument - Would it be possible to safely convert it to a function pointer and back (that is if it isn't possible to directly export __clrcall functions) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `foo` is inside a public managed type, you can add a reference to your C++/CLI assembly and use it from e.g. C# just as you would any other managed assembly. The `StandardOutputError` delegate is already fine.

The larger point is, managed types are exported in .NET metadata just by virtue of being managed types and compiling with /clr. No `__declspec(dllexport)` shenanigans necessary.

Comment: Oh yeah! Didn't occur to me to add it as a reference. Thanks!